# What old black and white movie involved taking an axe to an alien's corpus callosum?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Scitech Daily's [Brains of Cosmonauts “Rewired” During Space Missions](https://scitechdaily.com/brains-of-cosmonauts-rewired-during-space-missions/) links to the new paper in Frontiers in Neural Circuits [Brain Connectometry Changes in Space Travelers After Long-Duration Spaceflight](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncir.2022.815838/full) where MRI is used to study the brain connectome changes of cosmonauts associated with an average of six month aboard the International Space Station.

The abstract includes the following:

> We found significant microstructural changes in several large white matter tracts, such as the **corpus callosum**, arcuate fasciculus, corticospinal, corticostriatal, and cerebellar tracts. This is the first paper to use fiber tractography to investigate which specific tracts exhibit structural changes after long-duration spaceflight and may direct future research to investigate brain functional and behavioral changes associated with these white matter pathways.

Seeing *corpus callosum* I had a flashback to a moment when as a child I remember a scientist instructing someone that to kill an alien with a giant brain he had to deliver a fatal blow to the center of the brain. I don't remember if he said "corpus callosum" specifically or some other central structure, but it rings a bell.

**Question:** What old black and white movie involved a scientist instructing someone to take an axe to an alien's corpus callosum or nearby brain structure?

It would have been old enough to be shown on television some Sunday afternoon circa 1970 plus or minus.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [*The Brain from Planet Arous*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050210/) (1957).

An evil alien brain instructs a minion to kill an opponent by striking them at the ["*fissure of Rorlando*"](https://www.britannica.com/science/cerebral-fissure)

Comment: omg "oxygen" yes this is it! Geez it's *still scaring me* all these years later.